# How can we include the cell formula while export to excel from .rdlc

Tags: excel, report, export-to-excel, rdlc, reportviewer

In my `rdlc` report have following columns

```
SlNo, Item, Uom, Qty, Rate, Amount
```

Here the `Amount` field is a formula (`Rate*Qty`)

The report is working fine, and when i export to excel also displaying the values are correctly. 
But my problem is, after export to excel, when i change the `Qty` or `Rate` columns in excel file the `Amount` is not get changed automatically, because the formula is missing in the excel cell.
How can we include the formula in `Amount` column while export to excel from `.rdlc`?

Comment: This is an old post so i don't know if things have changed since then https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ddf11bf-e10f-4a3e-bd6a-d666eacb5ce4/report-viewer-export-ms-report-data-to-excel-with-formula?forum=vsreportcontrols  I guess you can check if it was a requested feature and how that progressed or follow up on the link to the open source project mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that this required behaviour isn't really possible by just using the rdlc rendering.

In my search I stumbled upon this same link that QHarr posted: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ddf11bf-e10f-4a3e-bd6a-d666eacb5ce4/report-viewer-export-ms-report-data-to-excel-with-formula?forum=vsreportcontrols 
I haven't tried the project that they're suggesting but this might possibly be your best solution if it works. Unfortunately I do not have the time to test it myself, so if you test this please share your results.

---

I thought of the following workaround that seems to work most of the times, but isn't really that reliable because the formula sometimes gets displayed as full-text instead of being calculated. But I guess this could be solved by editing the excel file just after being exported, and changing the cell properties of this column containing the formula or just triggering the *calculate*.

Using the built-in-field `Globals!RenderFormat.Name` you can determine the render mode, this way you can display the result correctly when the report is being rendered to something different than Excel. When you export to Excel, you could change the value of the cell to the actual formula. 
To form the formula it's self you'll need to figure this out on your own, but the `RowNumber(Scope as String)` function can be of use here to determine the row number of your cells.

Here is a possible example for the expression value of your *amount* column

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name LIKE "EXCEL*", "=E" & Cstr(RowNumber("DataSet1")+2) & "*F" & Cstr(RowNumber("DataSet1")+2) ,Fields!Rate.Value * Fields!Qty.Value )
```

Now considering that this formula sometimes gets displayed as full-text, and you'll probably have to edit the file post-rendering. If it's too complicated to determine which row/column the cell is on, you could also do this post-rendering. But I believe that the above expression should be easy enough to use to get your desired result without having to do much after rendering.

---

**Update:** The following code could be used to force the calculation of the formula (post rendering)

```
var fpath = @"C:\MyReport.xlsx";
using (var fs = File.Create(fpath))
{
    var lr = new LocalReport();
    //Initializing your reporter
    lr.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MyReport.rdlc";

    //Rendering to excel
    var fbytes = lr.Render("Excel");
    fs.Write(fbytes, 0, fbytes.Length);
}

var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application() { Visible = false };
var wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fpath);
var ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
var range = ws.UsedRange;
foreach (var cell in range.Cells)
{
    var cellv = cell.Text as string;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cellv) && cellv.StartsWith("="))
    {
        cell.Formula = cellv;
    }
}
wb.Save();
wb.Close(0);
xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: `Globals!RenderFormat.Name` is only available in `SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2`, and `server report`.
Currently, all versions of local report(`.rdlc`) doesn't include this built-in feature.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed - In the designer the `Name` part is underlined as if this is wrong code, but I assure you that it works. I used a local report where I pass a dataset without any SQL Server interaction. But if it doesn't work for you, depending on your requirement I hope you can still figure out a workaround. Like if you only ever render the report to Excel, you don't even need the property. Else I'm afraid you'll have to edit the cells post rendering. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your support, i just tested the workaround you are suggested. Almost closed. But now the formula `=E*F` is directly displaying in the excel column, when i just select that cell and press `ENTER key` then only the formula executed and calculated the value, other wise its directly showing formula as text. Any idea?

Comment: @AbdulRasheed -  I've added an example now, depending what action is starting the render, you can just queue something like in my example afterwards.